# Спустя — этимология

Tags: этимология, словообразование, значение-слов

Какова этимология слова **спустя**?
Например, "спустя 5 лет".
Может, исторически это в том смысле, что автор опускает/пропускает какой-то период времени?
 Нечто вроде "...опуская случившееся в последующие 5 лет, Марфа родила сына".

Comment: Есть собственная версия, или она совпадает с общепринятой?

Comment: @shampar https://lexicography.online/etymology/vasmer/search?s=%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F общепринятая не обнаружена.

Comment: Значит — есть своя?

Comment: А что не так в слове "спустя"? Каково понимание слова "спустя" - например: "спустя 5 лет"? Что не так? На что ответ давать?

Comment: ну спустя рукава - понятно, а лета куда спускают?

Comment: Не сами лета спускают, а их исчисление. Иначе: спускаясь лестницей = спускаете ступени?

Answer (score 4):

[**спустя́**](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F)
*Предлог с вин. п.* По прошествии чего-нибудь, позднее чего-нибудь, после того как прошло (какое-то время). *Спустя час отправились дальше. Спустя год разыгрались события. Спустя лето по малину в лес не ходят* (пословица).
[В значении "по прошествии какого-либо времени" предлоги **спустя** и **через** равнозначны.]

Производный предлог (*спустя*), образовываясь от знаменательного слова, обретает новое лексическое значение, отличное от значения мотивирующего слова (от деепричастия *спустя*).
Часто эта связь (более или менее тесная) может сохраняться.
Вот что нашлось в словаре [Даля](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/358806/%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%A3%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%AC):
**спускать**
Спустя лето, да в лес по малину! **упустя (пропустя)**.

Спустя пять лет (через пять лет, по истечении пяти лет, по прошествии пяти лет) = пропустив пять лет.

*По каким-то причинам публикация не состоялась, затем стихотворение затерялось среди многочисленных черновиков, и только сейчас, почти **тридцать пять лет спустя** после создания, приходит к читателю* (В. Есипов).

*Вторая запись в дневнике появляется **спустя пять лет**, когда Толстой находится во французском городе Гиере...* (П. Басинский)